# How to resolve: Credential should be scoped to a valid region, not 'queue'?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I'm using AWS SQS SDJ Java to setup sqs for a project. Currently, I have set up my SQS with region us-east-2. The SQS is: 
https://us-east-2.queue.amazonaws.com/... with other details at the end of the link. The AccessKey and SecretAccessKey seem to be set up properly. The endpoint is set up as per the proper documentation.

I'm getting the following error: Credential should be scoped to a valid region, not 'queue'. Below is the full error message. Would anyone know how to resolve this error? Thanks in advance.

```
    com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.AmazonSQSException: Credential should be scoped to a valid region, not 'queue'. (Service: AmazonSQS; Status Code: 403; Error Code: SignatureDoesNotMatch; Request ID: e39c7c41-8d5a-5a61-ba0e-2b1c52546c22; Proxy: null)
 at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1811)
 at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleServiceErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1395)
 at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1371)
 at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1145)
 at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:802)
 at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)
 at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:744)
 at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:704)
 at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:686)
 at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:550)
 at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:530)
 at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.doInvoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:2207)
 at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.invoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:2174)
 at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.invoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:2163)
 at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.executeSendMessage(AmazonSQSClient.java:1762)
 at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.sendMessage(AmazonSQSClient.java:1734)
 at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.sendMessage(AmazonSQSClient.java:1774)
 at com.AWSSQS.sendMessageToQueue(AWSSimpleQueueServiceUtil.java:119)
 at com.sendToSQS(Helper.java:335)
 at com.Steps.sendMessageSQS(Steps.java:134)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the end point should be `https://sqs.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/...` ?
[SQS endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sqs-service.html)